# How can I add text to dropzone's form in rails?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dropzone.js

I'm currently trying to apply css I found in codepen [link](https://codepen.io/beben-koben/pen/KCsfA)
to the following rails code

`= file_field_tag "work_images[]", type: :file, multiple: true, accept: 'image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png', class: 'dropzone'`

I'm used to using something like this usually,

```
= link_to '<div></div>'.html_safe, work_image_path, class: ''
```

So I am having trouble adding description to the rails code...
How could I make this work?

Comment: What does your current css look like?

Comment: I wrote css exactly same with what codepen had. (Except I changed the # to . since I had dropzone named under a class) @jdgray

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the class to show up in the HTML:

```
= file_field_tag "work_images[]", 
                 type: :file,
                 multiple: true, 
                 accept: 'image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png', 
                 input_html: { class: 'dropzone' } do 
  = "Drop files here"
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually what I want to achieve is add text that says"drop files here" to this rails code I wrote. So dropzone itself is already working.

Comment: Updated to show adding text via a block. I think that works.